# Why my CSS class isn't added in my select field on Moodle 3.7 plugin?

Tags: php, html, css, moodle

I'm having trouble passing from version 3.5 of moodle to version 3.7. I have a plugin on it which have an interface perfectly working on moodle 3.5 and not on moodle 3.7.

When I'm adding a select in a moodleform, with the class attributes:

```
$select = $mform->createElement('select', 'cohorts', '', array(), array('size'=>15, 'class'=>'cohorts-selector'));
$mform->addElement($select);
```

The $mform object correctly contains the class attributes. But when HTML is generated, I get this result under 3.5 :

```html
<select size="15" class="cohorts-selector" name="cohorts[]" multiple="multiple" id="id_cohorts">
```

And this under 3.7:

```html
<select class="form-control" name="cohorts[]" id="id_cohorts" multiple="" size="15"></select>
</select>
```

In class there is not my cohorts-selector class.

I supposed they made change in the core of moodle that affect the adding of css class. So is there a new way to insert css class in an element ?

Comment: Are you sure the line of code is the same? Because I can also see multiple="multiple" under your 3.7 HTML code.
Maybe you are checking the wrong HTML OR it is possible that naming your input as "cohorts" is causing problems. Try renaming it and see

Comment: I found something like we cannot add our own css class directly on select in moodle 3.7 but this class is added on a div surrounding the select, so I change a bit my style.css class to take that into account. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who need it, I found a solution.

We apparently cannot add our own css class directly on select in moodle 3.7 but this class is added on a div surrounding the select, so I change a bit my style.css class to take that into account.